# Sumsets with the property "$A+B=C$ implies $A=C-B$"

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, sumsets

Let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group and $A$, $B$ and $C$ be finite subsets of $G$ with $A+B=C$. One may conclude that $A\subset C-B$. However, $A$ need not be equal to $C-B$. What is a necessary and sufficient condition to have $A=C-B$?

Comment: You may want to take the following into account while looking for a characterization of the pairs $(A,B)$ with $A=(A+B)−B$: Assume $G$ is finite (and possibly non-abelian). It's folklore (see, e.g., Lemma 3.1.2 in Chap. 3 of Geroldinger & Ruzsa's _Combinatorial Number Theory and Additive Group Theory_) that, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $G$ with $|G|<|A|+|B|$, then $A+B=G$, with the result that $A=(A+B)−B$ iff $A=G$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes such pairs are characterized in the case at least one of  $A$ or $B$ is large enough. I was thinking that for small sets, possibly $A\cup B$ being a Sidon set might give us a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of whether $A,\ B$, and $G$ are finite or infinite, the necessary and sufficient condition is that $B$ lies in a coset of the *period* (or *stabilizer*) of $A$, defined to be the subgroup of all those group elements $g$ with $A+g=A$.

To see this, notice that $A\subseteq (A+B)-B$ holds true in a trivial way, so that your condition reduces to $(A+B)-B\subseteq A$, which is thus equivalent to $A+(b_1-b_2)=A$ for any $b_1,b_2\in B$.

Comment: Thank you. May I include this as a remark in my paper?(of course with addressing it in the acknowledgment)

Comment: @Shahab: This is a very basic observation, you certainly can use it without any acknowledgement.

Answer (score 3):

The condition you want is very restrictive, at least when $G$ is finite. Notice that for any two non-empty subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $G$, one has $|X\pm Y|\geq |X|$. Indeed, if $G$ is a cyclic group of prime order, by the [Cauchy-Davenport Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem), the equality is achieved if and only if $|Y|=1$ or $X=G$. Now notice that $|C=A+B|\geq |A|$ and $|C-B|\geq |C|$. So if $C-B=A$, then we have $|C|=|A|$ and equality should be achieved in both $|A+B|\geq |A|$ and $|C-B|\geq |C|$. In the case of cyclic groups of prime order, the only possibilities are $A=C=G$ or $|B|=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Cauchy-Davenport theorem has a generalization for arbitrary abelian groups as follows: $|A+B|\geq \min\{p(G), |A|+|B|-1\}$, where $p(G)$ stands for the size of the smallest nontrivial subgroup of $G$. So we may repeat your argument for small subsets of abelian groups. However, when $|A|+|B|-1>p(G)$ we may need another argument.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz Fixed, thanks.